# DocuSign OAuth login Cancel link redirects to wrong URL

Tags: redirect, oauth, docusignapi, cancellation

The Cancel link on the OAuth login page attempts to redirect to the wrong URL. The host name from `redirect_uri` is replaced with `accound-d.docusign.com`.

OAuth page:
`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?`

Attempted redirect on cancel:
`https://account-d.docusign.com/<path and query from passed in redirect_uri>`

I don't see any additional URI parameters that can be passed in as part of the request:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/config-and-auth
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

How can I set the Cancel return URL?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the URL of the **Cancel** button of the DocuSign OAuth consent screen (see below) cannot be set at this time. I have submitted DocuSign internal enhancement request # ID-4173.

To help raise its priority, please ask your DocuSign technical or business contact to add your organization's information to the ID-4173 ticket.

[image]